# How do I set Ctrl+Alt+something for Audacious global hokeys?

Tags: music, audacious

I want to set up global hotkeys in Audacious as follows. When I try and set these up it doesn't allow two mask keys.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for play.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> for pause.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> for stop.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> for previous track.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> for next track.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> for volume up.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> for volume down.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> for skip back.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> for skip forward.

Comment: Is using the Gnome Shortcuts plug-in an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you use gnome, just run `gnome-keybinding-properties` and configure to your taste